# Best way to read JSON strings from Instagram API with R

Tags: json, r, api, instagram

I tried different approaches so far including `fromJSON(readLines(url),unexpected.escape="keep")`
and  `fromJSON(getURL(url),unexpected.escape="keep")`.
The thing I stumbled upon now is that if my request looks as follows:

`url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/142121981/?client_id=****************************"`
(fill in your clientid) combined with `readLines()`, which has worked better for me so far, I recieve the error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open: HTTP status was '400 BAD REQUEST'
```

If you open this URL in your browser u still get a JSON atring:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotFoundError","code":400,"error_message":"this user does not exist"}}
```

Telling me, that a user with this ID doesnt exist.

What I want is a alternative to `readLines()` that still reads in this JSON string instead of throwing an error.

Hope this is explanation enough! If not ask me anything you need to know!

Comment: Have you tried the `httr` or `RCurl` packages? You have many more options with those libraries for shaping your request and explicitly specifying headers and such. Make sure you form the exact type of request the API specifies.

Comment: I will look deeper into those libraries. But this is the request the API wants to see. If I use an existing UserID it works fine!

Comment: I see. Readlines just doesn't expect a status code of anything other than 200 to be useful. Those other libraries allow more control over what is returned.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tips by MrFlick I dived into the `httr`package.
The solution for me (or best practice) is to use

```
response = fromJSON(rawToChar(GET(url)))
```

This gives back an R object even if the user doesnt exist.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `fromJSON(rawToChar((GET(url1))$content))`

Answer (score 0):

I use RCurl, httr & RJSONIO packages and:

```
fromJSON(getURL()))
```